# Javascript wshell.run not working properly

Tags: javascript, hta, wsh

I'm using HTA and in it I have a function that should run a command line with wshell.run , If I'm writing this line in Windows 'Run' util it is working fine, I want it to work also in the HTA with wshell.run.

The line is:

> C:\xxxx\xxx\xxx.EXE aaa.psl abc

*( The names are xxx just in here - not in the real code.. )*

In the javascript code I'm using:

```
function runCmd()
{
 wshShell.exec( "C:\xxxx\xxx\xxx.EXE aaa.psl abc" );
}
```

The error I got is in the xxx.EXE application says ***"couldn't open aaa.psl File not found".***

Thanks,
Rotem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okkkk T.J. is the man!! :)

I finnaly made it with your help by replacing exec to run:

**This is the final (and working) code:**

```
function runCmd()
{
wshShell.CurrentDirectory = "G:\\xxx\\xxx";
wshShell.run( "xxx.EXE xxx.psl abc" ); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised the xxx.EXE program is running at all. You need to escape those backslashes in the command:

```
wshShell.Exec( "C:\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxx.EXE aaa.psl abc" );
//                ^-----^----^--- here
```

If you're doing the same thing in the `aaa.psl` filename, that's your problem.

If you're not passing a full path to the `aaa.psl` file, then most programs (not all) will expect it to be in the *current directory*, so you'll want to make sure you've set the current directory correctly (although using absolute paths may be a better option).

Here's an example, for instance, of telling Notepad to edit a file:

```
shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe c:\\temp\\temp.txt");
```

...or via the current directory:

```
shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.CurrentDirectory = "c:\\temp";
shell.Exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe temp.txt");
```

Comment: +1 that's probably the issue.  You can set the working directory with the [*wshShell.CurrentDirectory*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc5edzd\(v=VS.85\).aspx) property.

Comment: @Andy E: Oddly, I was just adding an example... :-)

Comment: Heh, well another +1 then.  Unfortunately I had to remove the previous +1 before I could add the second ;-)

Comment: Hi, about the backslash I'm afraid it isn't true. If you write '/' it's fine with one slash, otherwise if you write '\' so you will need to use '\\' this is why it's working :) Now it's opening the application like earlier but it just exits without propmt any message.. More ideas? thanks!

Comment: @Rotem: *"about the backslash I'm afraid it isn't true. If you write '/' it's fine with one slash"* Yes, it would be. Your question uses \, not /. *"More ideas?"* No, not without seeing the actual code.

Comment: This is the actual code - only 1 line (the one I wrote in the question) , not more than that. I don't know more about the application I'm running, all I know is if I write the same line on windows run it's working fine. Any ideas? Please... :(

Comment: If this is the actual code, then I've already pointed out what the problems are -- you need to escape your backslashes and either ensure that you're in the correct directory when issuing the `Exec` or give the full path to the `aaa.psl` file.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested, it didn't work. now the function is: runCmd() { wshShell.CurrentDirectory = "G://xxx//xxx"; wshShell.exec( "xxx.EXE xxx.psl abc" ); } I tried writing the slashes in both ways.. The application is reacting in different way, it is now opens the app. and then closes with no error..

Comment: @Rotem: Now you've put in double **slashes** ( / ). You should have double **backslashes** ( \ ). Actually look -- really *look* -- at the example I gave, which works. Or use copy and paste. This is computer stuff, being precise **really matters**. </rant> :-)

Comment: I wrote you that I tried all combinations including ofcourse the same as you wrote in your answer. It is not working, the apllication opens and then just closes. I obviously tried what you wrote - I'm here to learn :)